# How to simplify a join of 2 tables in HIVE and count values

Tags: hiveql

I have two tables in HIVE, "orders" and "customers". I want to get top n user names of users who placed most orders (in status "CLOSED"). Orders table has key order_customer_id, column order_status and customers has key customer_id and name consists of 2 columns customer_fname and customer_lname.

```
ORDERS
order_customer_id, order_status
1,CLOSED
2,CLOSED
3,INPROGRESS
1,INPROGRESS
1,CLOSED
2,CLOSED

CUSTOMERS
customer_id, customer_fname, customer_lname
1,Mickey, Mouse
2,Henry, Ford
3,John, Doe
```

I tried this code:

```
select c.customer_id, count(o.order_customer_id) as COUNT, concat(c.customer_fname," ",c.customer_lname) as FULLNAME from customers c join orders o on c.customer_id=o.order_customer_id where o.order_status='CLOSED' group by c.customer_id,FULLNAME order by COUNT desc limit 10;
```

this does not work - returns error.

I was able to get the result by first creating a 3rd table:

```
create table id_sum as select o.order_customer_id,count(o.order_id) as COUNT from orders o join customers c on c.customer_id=o.order_customer_id where order_status='CLOSED' group by o.order_customer_id;

1833    6
5493    5
1363    5
1687    5
569     4
1764    4
1345    4
```

Then I joined the tables:

```
select s.*,concat(c.customer_fname," " ,c.customer_lname) from id_sum s join customers c on s.order_customer_id = c.customer_id order by count desc limit 20;
```

This resulted in desired output:

```
customer_id, order_count, full_name
1833    6       Ronald Smith
5493    5       Mary Cochran
1363    5       Kathy Rios
1687    5       Jerry Ellis
569     4       Mary Frye
1764    4       Megan Davila
1345    4       Adam Wilson
```

Is there a way how to write it in one command or more effectively?

Comment: Input and Output Data don't match.

Comment: In Mysql the query you say that returns an error works fine:https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/a9YwPE593XiL7bmdkiWJvn/0 So I guess the Mysql tag is irrelevant.

Comment: I think the word 'COUNT' is a reserved keyword.  If you just change your query to this it should work `select c.customer_id, count(o.order_customer_id) as row_count, concat(c.customer_fname," ",c.customer_lname) as FULLNAME from customers c join orders o on c.customer_id=o.order_customer_id where o.order_status='CLOSED' group by c.customer_id,concat(c.customer_fname," ",c.customer_lname) order by row_count desc limit 10;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The subquery with alias **sq** creates a relation with two columns order_count and customer_id calculating for each customer_id the total number of orders. This is then joined with the CUSTOMERS table. The result is sorted descending and limited to (the top) 10 rows.

```
SELECT c.customer_id, sq.order_count, concat(c.customer_fname," " ,c.customer_lname) as full_name
FROM CUSTOMERS c JOIN (
    SELECT COUNT(*) as order_count, order_customer_id FROM ORDERS
    WHERE order_status = 'CLOSED'
    GROUP BY order_customer_id
) sq on c.customer_id = sq.order_customer_id
ORDER BY sq.order_count desc LIMIT 10
;
```

The idea is to use a subquery instead of a third table.

Comment: Thank you very much. Your solution worked correct, but with slight correction:

`SELECT c.customer_id, sq.order_count, concat(c.customer_fname," " ,c.customer_lname) as full_name
FROM CUSTOMERS c JOIN (
    SELECT COUNT(*) as order_count, order_customer_id FROM ORDERS
    WHERE order_status = 'CLOSED'
    GROUP BY order_customer_id
) sq on c.customer_id = sq.order_customer_id
ORDER BY sq.order_count desc LIMIT 10
;`

The ORDERS table column name is orders_customer_id.

Comment: Actually the answer from @deusexmach1na brought me to an idea and by replacing the **COUNT** with **mycount** and for unknown reason seems like in HIVE the aliasing does not work as expected. Simply by removing the alias **FULLNAME** with the full meaning the code worked. So like this:

`select c.customer_id, count(o.order_customer_id) as mycount, concat(c.customer_fname," ",c.customer_lname) from customers c join orders o on c.customer_id=o.order_customer_id where o.order_status='CLOSED' group by c.customer_id,concat(c.customer_fname," ",c.customer_lname) order by mycount desc limit 10;`

Comment: @Katakrossis Sorry about that! I think I updated the SQL with the correct column name now.